# automatically add a class to source control

Tags: java, eclipse, clearcase

I am using clear case and eclipse. I want eclipse to prompt me to add a new class to source control everytime i create a new class. I am sure there is an option to do this I just can't figure out where exactly. If someone knows how that would be great!

Comment: Friends don't let friends use ClearCase! ;)

Comment: @isnot2bad but if said friends let friends use ClearCase, they know they can count on me. For the past five years: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/clearcase/topusers

Comment: Are you sure you want to source control the class files? Why? Normally only the sourcefiles are added to version control since the class files can easily be created from the source files. Any change you make will then require two checkouts.

Comment: yea i menat the source file. Of cousre when you create a class you create a source not a class immediately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and selection the option:

**When new resources are added: "Prompt to add to source control"**

(With the official [IBM ClearCase SCM adapter plugin for Eclipse](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21256383))

[image: new resources prompt]